# JSON to Array C#

Tags: c#, json, twitter

Trying to get all info from a json file into an array with C# using Newtonsoft.Json only.

```
    namespace tslife
    {
        partial class game
        {           

        world[] game_intro = _read_world<world>("intro");

        //** other code **//

        public void update()
        {
            //crashes: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
            Console.WriteLine(game_intro[0].data.Text);        
        }

        private static T[] _read_world<T>(string level)
        {           
            var json_data = string.Empty;
            string st = "";
            try
            {
                var stream = File.OpenText("Application/story/"+level+".json"); 
                //Read the file              
                st = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch(SystemException e){}
            json_data = st;

            //Console.WriteLine(json_data);
            // if string with JSON data is not empty, deserialize it to class and return its instance 
            T[] dataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(json_data);
            return dataObject;
         }
    }
}   


  public class worldData {
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public string Icon { get; set; }
  public int sectionID { get; set; }
} 

public class world
{
    public worldData data;
}
```

I don't know if it is the formatting of the json however, but I'm stuck after searching else where.

```
[{
    "world":
        {
            "Text":"Hi",
            "Icon":"image01.png",
            "sectionID": 0
        }
},
{
    "world":
        {
            "Text":"Hey",
            "Icon":"image02.png",
            "sectionID": 1
        }
}
]
```

Comment: can you try replacing `public worldData data;` with `public worldData world {get; set;}` and let us know what happens?

Comment: I originally had it that, still didn't work.

Comment: You get an empty array, right? Can you get rid of that empty catch please?

Comment: You can't have had public worldData world {get; set;} inside class world because that doesn't compile....

Comment: rene... OOP IO rule... always catch when reading a file. So no!

Comment: I'm not playing games rene, I guessed you mostly ment the {get; set;} part, and I told you I originally had that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In serialization and deserialization without annotation the membernames need to match your JSON structure.

The class world and worldData are OK-ish but the world class is missing the property `world`.

If I change your class structure to this:

```
public class worldData {
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public string Icon { get; set; }
  public int sectionID { get; set; }
} 

// notice I had to change your classname
// because membernames cannot be the same as their typename 
public class worldroot
{
        public worldData world { get; set; }
}
```

I can deserialize your json in an array whicjh gives me two elements:

```
var l = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<worldroot[]>(json);
```

And on the catching of exceptions: Only catch exceptions if you are going to do something sensible with them.

```
        try
        {
            var stream = File.OpenText("Application/story/"+level+".json"); 
            //Read the file              
            st = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch(SystemException e){}
```

empty catches like that are useless and only hinder in debugging. You can live with [unchecked exceptions](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/03/living-with-unchecked-exceptions/).

Comment: Thanks, so the variable has to be the same as the Json variable. Good to know now. I just changed the class to _world as it is only needed at initialization.